# My legend doesn't appear

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

l tried to  show my legend inside and outside the figure but still can't see it. it just the empty box.what's wrong

```
p1=plt.plot(np.logspace(-2,1,10), trainsScores, label="train scores")
p2=plt.plot(np.logspace(-2,1,10), testScores, label="test scores")
plt.legend([p1, p2], ["Train score", "Test score"], loc='upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you not get a warning printed on the console?

```
UserWarning: Legend does not support [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f7a9a442518>] instances.
```

There you have the explanation. `p1` and `p2` are lists and you can't pass lists as legend handles.

```
>>> print(type(p1))
<class 'list'>
```

Assign the `Line2D` instances to `p1` and `p2` and it will work.

```
p1, = plt.plot(np.logspace(-2,1,10), np.random.rand(10), label="train scores")
p2, = plt.plot(np.logspace(-2,1,10), np.random.rand(10), label="test scores")
plt.legend([p1, p2], ["Train score", "Test score"], loc='upper center',
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05), fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.show()
```

[image]